# Use Each on an array to iterate over and return the index of greater values

Tags: ruby, arrays, while-loop, each

```
a = [2,2,4,8,9]
ind = 1

a.each do |x|

if a[ind] < a[x]
puts x
end

end
```

How can I use "each" on an array to iterate over and return the index of all values greater than a certain value in Ruby?

I would like to iterate over the given array `a = [2,2,4,8,9]`. I want to iterate over the entire array and, using a conditional, put out all values where `a[ind] < a[x]`.

I receive the error `comparison of fixnum nil failed`. - How can I resolve this?

I did try this as well, seting a range for the process:

```
    a = [ 2,2,3,4,5]

x = 0
while x >= 0 && x <= 4

a.each do |x|
    if a[1] < a[x]
        puts x
    end

end
x += 1 
end
```

Comment: Your question is kind of difficult to understand. I think the wording can be improved.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good catch, I guess I clipped it.  Let me redact that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are iterating over an array using `each` the `x` denotes the *value* of the item, not its position:

```
a = [2,2,4,8,9]
ind = 1

a.each do |x|
  if a[ind] < x
    puts x
  end
end
# prints:
# 4
# 8
# 9
```

---

Update:

If you want to print the *indexes* of the elements with value greater than the value, you should use `each_with_index`:

```
a = [2,2,4,8,9]
ind = 1

a.each_with_index do |x, i|
  if a[ind] < x
    puts i
  end
end
# prints:
# 2
# 3
# 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to select all elements whose index is less than themselves. You can just say exactly that in Ruby:

```
a.select.with_index {|el, idx| idx < el }
```

or even

```
a.select.with_index(&:>)
```

Comment: How did you figure that this is what he needs?

Comment: `with_index(&:>)` is a working code.. but for a while it seem to me, you forgot to pass the block `{ ||..}`.. Lollz

Comment: Good one, you would just need to fix the operator symbol in the 2nd example to `:>=`.

Comment: @DavidUnric: Nope, but I made the same mistake as you. I'm *not* flipping the logic, I'm just reading right-to-left. I.e. I'm not using the identity `a < b == !(a >= b)`, I'm using the identity `a > b == b < a`.

Comment: @UriAgassi: I have no idea :-D The question is much less clear now, after the third-party edit, though. The spelling, grammar and formatting have vastly improved, but the central sentence about the value being less than the index has been completely deleted.

Comment: After re-reading the OP's original version - I think we both got it wrong - I now believe he wanted to print all the _indexes_ of the items whose values are _greater than `a[ind]`_ (I've updated my answer accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

```
def filtered_index(array,n)
  array.each_with_index{|e,i| puts i if e > n}
end
```

Comment: Please explain in your answer what this code does and how it solves the problem. Code-only answers are not useful to beginners trying to understand the solution.